# Telerik asp.net client side validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, validation, telerik

I want to client validate a form before postback so I'm using the onclientclick event to validate the form and if it's valid, do some server side stuff.

here  my code:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" id="Script1">
        function performCheck() {
            return $("TextBox1").val() == "";
        }
</script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
        <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">

        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="thisGpo"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="true"  ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="thisGpo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:Button OnClientClick="performCheck()"  ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="thisGpo" CausesValidation="true" />     </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Problem is, if I use telerik controls,  they add the tag

```
    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

and this thing form hell is causing postbacks overring my code, so it is frustrating.

My boss force us to use of Telerik because they have this fancy numericTextbox and he is paying.

Tried to contact TELERIK but they mentioned they can't give us support because our version has expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the experienced behavior was the Unobtrusive validation which is the default validation for project build against the .Net 4.5 version.

So When you create .NET 4.5 Telerik Web Site, the default web form has a RadScriptManager. This means that the version of jQuery that goes with the Telerik controls is registered with the ScriptManager as jquery, so you need to specify the order in which jQuery and the validation scripts are registered.The validation scripts of the unobtrusive validation (WebForms.js and WebUIValidation.js) are not available in this case, so you also need to install them on the site.
The steps below to setup the unobtrusive validation:
Open TOOLS > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console and run the following command to install the Microsoft Ajax optimization bundle for Web Forms with ScriptManager:

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.WebForms -Version x.x.x (you can check the current version of this NuGet package in its download page).This will install the script files WebForms.js and WebUIValidation.js on the web site.

Configure RadScriptManager to specify that jQuery is registered before the validation scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want client side validation you can add 'return false;' to the OnClientClick

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="performCheck(); return false;"  ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="thisGpo" CausesValidation="true" />
```

Then to have the server side called I would suggest either creating a hidden button that calls the server side method or use ajax.

Using hidden button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDoTheThing" style="display: none;" OnClick="btnDoThething_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Server side code:

```
protected void btnDoTheThing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            // Do The Thing
}
```

So once the javascript validation is complete and is valid, then use jquery to click the button with a call like

```
$("#btnDoTheThing").click();
```

Alternatively you can use Ajax to call the server side code once the validation is valid.

Comment: more like a workaround but thanks, I really appreciate it!!